# Difference between binary semaphore and mutex

Tags: operating-system, mutex, semaphore, binary-semaphore

Is there any difference between a binary semaphore and mutex or are they essentially the same?

Comment: They're semantically the same, but in practice you will notice weird differences (especially on Windows).

Comment: @Michael Foukarakis: What are the weird differences?

Comment: I suppose weird wasn't the correct expression. A mutex also supports ownership and sometimes reentry. This is the case in Windows. In addition, semaphores in Windows are implemented on top of Event objects, however, I'm unsure of the practical implications of this.

Comment: Similar discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039899/when-should-we-use-mutex-and-when-should-we-use-semaphore

Comment: They are the same thing. Eg Hoare 1972 Monitors: An Operating System Structuring Concept "Obviously, we shall require for each monitor a Boolean semaphore "*rnutex*" to ensure that the bodies of the local procedures exclude each other. The semaphore is initialized to 1; a *P(mutex)* must be executed on entry to each local procedure, and a *V(mutex)* must usually be executed on exit from it." Various systems, languages, libraries etc use generic terms with specialized meaning. A word means what people agree it means. (If they can manage it.) Define your terms, and have others define theirs.

Comment: Btw, you should accept an answer :) So many good answers are down there waiting to be accepted tho I would say @Benoit answer is quite worthy.

Comment: @philipxy Nicely hid 'rn' in place of 'm'.

Comment: @Mooncrater Wow. Good eye. I expect its due to OCR. [(Yes, it is.)](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~shanlu/teaching/33100_fa15/papers/hoare-monitors.pdf)

Comment: i see lot of answers copied and pasted from http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/c3003/extra/difference-between-semaphore-and-mutex.html#:~:text=Mutex%20can%20be%20released%20only,like%20event%20objects%20than%20mutexes

Comment: If anyone prefer video watch this (https://youtu.be/8wcuLCvMmF8) video you will get clear understanding

Answer (score 816):

They are **NOT** the same thing.  They are used for different purposes!
While both types of semaphores have a full/empty state and use the same API, their usage is very different.

**Mutual Exclusion Semaphores**
Mutual Exclusion semaphores are used to protect shared resources (data structure, file, etc..).

A Mutex semaphore is "owned" by the task that takes it.  If Task B attempts to semGive a mutex currently held by Task A, Task B's call will return an error and fail.

Mutexes always use the following sequence:

```
  - SemTake
  - Critical Section
  - SemGive
```

Here is a simple example:

```
  Thread A                     Thread B
   Take Mutex
     access data
     ...                        Take Mutex  <== Will block
     ...
   Give Mutex                     access data  <== Unblocks
                                  ...
                                Give Mutex
```

**Binary Semaphore**
Binary Semaphore address a totally different question:

- Task B is pended waiting for something to happen (a sensor being tripped for example).
- Sensor Trips and an Interrupt Service Routine runs. It needs to notify a task of the trip.
- Task B should run and take appropriate actions for the sensor trip. Then go back to waiting.

```
   Task A                      Task B
   ...                         Take BinSemaphore   <== wait for something
   Do Something Noteworthy
   Give BinSemaphore           do something    <== unblocks
```

Note that with a binary semaphore, it is OK for B to take the semaphore and A to give it.
Again, a binary semaphore is NOT protecting a resource from access. The act of Giving and Taking a semaphore are fundamentally decoupled.
It typically makes little sense for the same task to call both give and take on the same binary semaphore.

Comment: Isn't a mutex better than a binary semaphore then? Since it doesn't make sense if someone releases a lock which he doesn't actually hold.

Comment: They have different purposes. Mutex is for exclusive access to a resource. A Binary semaphore should be used for Synchronization (i.e. "Hey Someone! This occurred!"). The Binary "giver" simply notifies whoever the "taker" that what they were waiting for happened.

Comment: @Pacerier You are confusing the purpose. A mutex is intended protect a critical region. You are correct it doesn't make sense to use a Binary Semaphore. I'll update the answer to explain the purpose of each.

Comment: @Benoit So Can we say that Mutex are Used for atomicity and Binary Semaphore for Ordering perspective since Task B will be waiting for Task A to signal the release of lock inherently making sure of ordering of operations on a data strurcture?

Comment: @abhi That's a good way to look at it for the Mutex. However, depending on the OS, you can have more than one recipient waiting on a binary semaphore. In that case, only one of the client will get the binary sem. The other(s) would wait for a subsequent one. Is the order of receiving known or guaranteed?  Depends on the OS.

Comment: @Benoit So if binary Semaphore is used for synchronization, then shouldn't Counting Semaphore be used in a similar sense? Could you pls tell how counting semaphore be used for synchronization among N tasks?

Comment: So would it be fair to say that boost::condition_variable (or std::condition_variable, since C++11) is really a semaphore?

Comment: Resources to supplement the answer: [binary](http://www.freertos.org/Embedded-RTOS-Binary-Semaphores.html)
 [mutex](http://www.freertos.org/Real-time-embedded-RTOS-mutexes.html)

Comment: @Benoit I noticed that the difference are in two way **intent** and **behavior**. These two words are also important in design patterns. I also noticed that the mutexes are more like state-pattern where the state changes by the algorithm that is selected by the state. And binary-semaphores are like strategy-pattern where the state can be changed by external algorithm.

Comment: The [little book of semaphores](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/LittleBookOfSemaphores.pdf) is a valuable read about these issues.

Comment: But from this explanation follows that semantically at some level it’s absolutely the same thing. The typical scenario of usage is different, some technical details of implementation may differ like possibility to unloc/signal from another thread. But otherwise it’s the same - program just waits for something to continue execution and another part of the program can make that “something“ happen.

Comment: This answer may be useful, but I don't see that this actually answers the question. I don't see any information on how mutexes and binary semaphores behave differently to achieve their differing intended goal. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: So, in another words, mutex is a special case of binary semaphore designed solely to accomplish resource lock task. While binary semaphore can be used both for signaling and lock task, depends on how you use it.

Comment: We should also add that in practice the additional semantics that are typically bundled with OS mutex APIs give *additional information* to the operating system that it can use to achieve more efficient thread scheduling. I.e. the OS can know "Thread A is waiting specifically for thread B", rather than simply "Thread A is waiting."

Comment: In linux, there is another HUGE difference that pthread_mutex_lock() is not a cancellation point while sem_wait() is. Please refer to Manual page pthreads(7) and pthread_cancel(3)

Answer (score 541):

- A **mutex** can be released only by **the thread that had acquired it**.
- A **binary semaphore** can be signaled **by any thread** (or process).

so semaphores are more suitable for some synchronization problems like producer-consumer.

On Windows, binary semaphores are more like event objects than mutexes.

Comment: `Mutex can be released only by thread that had acquired it` -- I just tried with a simple pthread_mutex based program, a thread can unlock mutex locked in main thread

Comment: @warl0ck As per the man page of pthread_mutex_lock http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock : "If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK, then error checking shall be provided....If a thread attempts to unlock a mutex that it has not locked or a mutex which is unlocked, an error shall be returned."

Comment: @warl0ck Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5492499/385064 'Pthreads has 3 different kinds of mutexes: Fast mutex, recursive mutex, and error checking mutex. You used a fast mutex which, for performance reasons, will not check for this error. If you use the error checking mutex on Linux you will find you get the results you expect.'

Comment: In our code we have used mutex also for synchronization purposes.The Thread which locks the mutex again tried to lock the mutex.Then it goes to blocked state.What we have seen is that we are able to unlock this from another thread .Thus achieving synchronization between the two.We are using posix standard only .So the major difference sited between mutex and binary semaphore seems vague.

Comment: @achoora I agree that it is wrong to specialize semaphore for synchronization. Actually all the mutex,binary-semaphore,barrier,pipelines are different patterns for synchronization. In design perspective, mutex are more like state-pattern where the algorithm that is selected by the state can change the state. The binary-semaphore are more like strategy pattern where the external algorithm can change the state and eventually the algorithm/strategy selected to run.

Answer (score 493):

[The Toilet example](http://koti.mbnet.fi/niclasw/MutexSemaphore.html) is an enjoyable analogy:

> Mutex:
>
> Is a key to a toilet. One person can
>   have the key - occupy the toilet - at
>   the time. When finished, the person
>   gives (frees) the key to the next
>   person in the queue.
>
> Officially: "Mutexes are typically
>   used to serialise access to a section
>   of  re-entrant code that cannot be
>   executed concurrently by more than one
>   thread. A mutex object only allows one
>   thread into a controlled section,
>   forcing other threads which attempt to
>   gain access to that section to wait
>   until the first thread has exited from
>   that section." Ref: Symbian Developer
>   Library
>
> (A mutex is really a semaphore with
>   value 1.)
>
> Semaphore:
>
> Is the number of free identical toilet
>   keys. Example, say we have four
>   toilets with identical locks and keys.
>   The semaphore count - the count of
>   keys - is set to 4 at beginning (all
>   four toilets are free), then the count
>   value is decremented as people are
>   coming in. If all toilets are full,
>   ie. there are no free keys left, the
>   semaphore count is 0. Now, when eq.
>   one person leaves the toilet,
>   semaphore is increased to 1 (one free
>   key), and given to the next person in
>   the queue.
>
> Officially: "A semaphore restricts the
>   number of simultaneous users of a
>   shared resource up to a maximum
>   number. Threads can request access to
>   the resource (decrementing the
>   semaphore), and can signal that they
>   have finished using the resource
>   (incrementing the semaphore)." Ref:
>   Symbian Developer Library

Comment: ... but this is regarding mutex vs counting semaphore. The question was asked about binary.

Comment: While what is said by david is correct, but it is NOT the answer to  the question asked. Mladen Jankovic answer is the answer to the question asked, where point is made to differentiate "binary-semaphore" vs "mutex".

Comment: Unfortunately, this incorrect answer has more votes than the best answer by @Benoit

Comment: A semaphore restricts the number of simultaneous users of a shared resource up to a maximum number. This is it. Thanks.

Comment: This answer is misleading.Should have compared only with Binary Semaphore.

Comment: This also demonstrates a problem with using a counting semaphore to protect a shared resource:  if the keys are indeed identical, and a toilet is unlocked using a key, and there is no other mechanism to distribute cubicle usage, then:  (1) the first user unlocks, enters and starts to use the first cubicle.  (2) the next user unlocks, enters and starts to use the first cubicle...

Comment: I don't see the problem - a binary semaphore is simply a counting semaphore where the max count is 1. The analogy still applies perfectly well. The difference is that the semaphore maintains a count.

Comment: @JacobRitchie the problem is with the statement that says "A mutex is really a semaphore with value 1" but that is not the case. ThreadA and only ThreadA can increment (and hence release) the mutex that it decremented whereas ThreadB can increment the binSemaphore decremented by ThreadA, which also happens to be the answer to the question in question.

Comment: In other words: A binary semaphore is identical to a mutex. Downvoted for presenting the information of a one-liner in several paragraphs. And not even addressing the question being asked.

Comment: So you're saying if I screw up a mutex I might end up in a bathroom crossing streams with some stranger!?

Comment: A row of toilets would correspond to an array of mutexes, not a semaphore.

Answer (score 178):

Nice articles on the topic:

- [MUTEX VS. SEMAPHORES – PART 1: SEMAPHORES](https://blog.feabhas.com/2009/09/mutex-vs-semaphores-%E2%80%93-part-1-semaphores/)
- [MUTEX VS. SEMAPHORES – PART 2: THE MUTEX](https://blog.feabhas.com/2009/09/mutex-vs-semaphores-%E2%80%93-part-2-the-mutex/)
- [MUTEX VS. SEMAPHORES – PART 3 (FINAL PART): MUTUAL EXCLUSION PROBLEMS](https://blog.feabhas.com/2009/10/mutex-vs-semaphores-%E2%80%93-part-3-final-part-mutual-exclusion-problems/)

**From part 2:**

> The mutex is similar to the principles
>   of the binary semaphore with one
>   significant difference: the principle
>   of ownership. Ownership is the simple
>   concept that when a task locks
>   (acquires) a mutex only it can unlock
>   (release) it. If a task tries to
>   unlock a mutex it hasn’t locked (thus
>   doesn’t own) then an error condition
>   is encountered and, most importantly,
>   the mutex is not unlocked. If the
>   mutual exclusion object doesn't have
>   ownership then, irrelevant of what it
>   is called, it is not a mutex.

Comment: Thanks for the link, the explanations there are excellent. The link has changed: http://www.feabhas.com/blog/2009/09/mutex-vs-semaphores-%E2%80%93-part-1-semaphores/ (Use < Prev and Next > to navigate to the other two articles.

Comment: Note - the lack of ownership also prevents the operating system from working around priority inversion. For this reason, I generally use condition variables as opposed to semaphores for producer/consumer architectures.

Comment: +1 foe excellent article links. The best article explaining semaphore and mutex with "what-it-is" and "what-it-does"

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/
I had used this article as my behind the scene reference, which technically does explain everything about mutex/conditionals and other constructs built on their top like semaphore/barrier/reader-writer, but nowhere explicit and concise about problems faced with constructs. In short it is reference. :)

Comment: more easily understood than the other answers.

Answer (score 117):

Since none of the above answer clears the confusion, here is one which cleared my confusion.

> Strictly speaking, **a mutex is a locking mechanism** used to
>   synchronize access to a resource. Only one task (can be a thread or
>   process based on OS abstraction) can acquire the mutex. It means there
>   will be ownership associated with mutex, and only the owner can
>   release the lock (mutex).
>
> **Semaphore is signaling mechanism** (“I am done, you can carry on” kind of signal). For example, if you are listening songs (assume it as
>   one task) on your mobile and at the same time your friend called you,
>   an interrupt will be triggered upon which an interrupt service routine
>   (ISR) will signal the call processing task to wakeup.

Source: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutex-vs-semaphore/

Answer (score 49):

Their synchronization semantics are very different:

- mutexes allow serialization of access to a given resource i.e. multiple threads wait for a lock, one at a time and as previously said, the thread *owns* the lock until it is done: **only** this particular thread can unlock it.
- a binary semaphore is a counter with value 0 and 1: a task blocking on it until **any** task does a sem_post. The semaphore advertises that a resource is available, and it provides the mechanism to wait until it is signaled as being available.

As such one can see a mutex as a token passed from task to tasks and a semaphore as traffic red-light (it **signals** someone that it can proceed).

Answer (score 33):

At a theoretical level, they are no different semantically.  You can implement a mutex using semaphores or vice versa (see [here](http://www.picturel.com/ucr/node32.html) for an example).  In practice, the implementations are different and they offer slightly different services.

The practical difference (in terms of the system services surrounding them) is that the implementation of a mutex is aimed at being a more lightweight synchronisation mechanism.  In oracle-speak, mutexes are known as [latches](http://dbataj.blogspot.com/2007/10/oracle-latch.html) and semaphores are known as [waits](http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_dbazine_waits.htm).

At the lowest level, they use some sort of atomic [test and set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set) mechanism.  This reads the current value of a memory location, computes some sort of conditional and writes out a value at that location in a single instruction that [cannot be interrupted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_operation).  This means that you can acquire a mutex and test to see if anyone else had it before you.

A typical mutex implementation has a process or thread executing the test-and-set instruction and evaluating whether anything else had set the mutex.   A key point here is that there is no interaction with the [scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)), so we have no idea (and don't care) who has set the lock.  Then we either give up our time slice and attempt it again when the task is re-scheduled or execute a [spin-lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock).  A spin lock is an algorithm like:

```
Count down from 5000:
     i. Execute the test-and-set instruction
    ii. If the mutex is clear, we have acquired it in the previous instruction 
        so we can exit the loop
   iii. When we get to zero, give up our time slice.
```

When we have finished executing our protected code (known as a [critical section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section)) we just set the mutex value to zero or whatever means 'clear.'  If multiple tasks are attempting to acquire the mutex then the next task that happens to be scheduled after the mutex is released will get access to the resource.  Typically you would use mutexes to control a synchronised resource where exclusive access is only needed for very short periods of time, normally to make an update to a shared data structure.

A semaphore is a synchronised data structure (typically using a mutex) that has a count and some system call wrappers that interact with the scheduler in a bit more depth than the mutex libraries would.  Semaphores are incremented and decremented and used to [block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(scheduling)) tasks until something else is ready.  See [Producer/Consumer Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) for a simple example of this.  Semaphores are initialised to some value - a binary semaphore is just a special case where the semaphore is initialised to 1.  Posting to a semaphore has the effect of waking up a waiting process.

A basic semaphore algorithm looks like:

```
(somewhere in the program startup)
Initialise the semaphore to its start-up value.

Acquiring a semaphore
   i. (synchronised) Attempt to decrement the semaphore value
  ii. If the value would be less than zero, put the task on the tail of the list of tasks waiting on the semaphore and give up the time slice.

Posting a semaphore
   i. (synchronised) Increment the semaphore value
  ii. If the value is greater or equal to the amount requested in the post at the front of the queue, take that task off the queue and make it runnable.  
 iii. Repeat (ii) for all tasks until the posted value is exhausted or there are no more tasks waiting.
```

In the case of a binary semaphore the main practical difference between the two is the nature of the system services surrounding the actual data structure.

EDIT: As evan has rightly pointed out, spinlocks will slow down a single processor machine.  You would only use a spinlock on a multi-processor box because on a single processor the process holding the mutex will never reset it while another task is running.  Spinlocks are only useful on multi-processor architectures.

Comment: I don't think it is common practice for a mutex to be implemented with spinlocks. On a Uni-proc machine this would be absolutely terrible for performance.

Comment: Normally you would only use spinlocks on multi-processor systems.

Comment: Even on SMP, after spinning a few times you fall-back to OS-assisted sleep/wake.  (e.g. the Linux `futex` system call exists to assist low-latency userspace mutex / semaphore implementations.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex)  In the no-contention fast path, or if the resource becomes available soon, you never have the overhead of a system call.  But you don't spend more than a few micro-seconds busy-waiting (spinning).  Tuning the parameters of spin-loop backoff and wait is hardware and workload-dependent, of course, but the standard library usually has reasonable choices.

Answer (score 21):

Though mutex & semaphores are used as synchronization primitives ,there is a big difference between them.
In the case of mutex, only the thread that locked or acquired the mutex can unlock it.
In the case of a semaphore, a thread waiting on a semaphore can be signaled by a different thread.
Some operating system supports using mutex & semaphores between process. Typically usage is creating in shared memory.

Comment: "can be signaled by a different thread" what is it mean give an example.

Answer (score 20):

Mutex: Suppose we have critical section thread T1 wants to access it then it follows below steps.
T1:

1. Lock
2. Use Critical Section
3. Unlock

Binary semaphore: It works based on signaling wait and signal.
wait(s) decrease "s" value by one usually "s" value is initialize with value "1",
signal(s) increases "s" value by one. if "s" value is 1 means no one is using critical section, when value is 0 means critical section is in use.
suppose thread T2 is using critical section then it follows below steps.
T2 :

1. wait(s)//initially s value is one after calling wait it's value decreased by one i.e 0
2. Use critical section
3. signal(s) // now s value is increased and it become 1

Main difference between Mutex and Binary semaphore is in Mutext if thread lock the critical section then it has to unlock critical section no other thread can unlock it, but in case of Binary semaphore if one thread locks critical section using wait(s) function then value of s become "0" and no one can access it until value of "s" become 1 but suppose some other thread calls signal(s) then value of "s" become 1 and it allows other function to use critical section.
hence in Binary semaphore thread doesn't have ownership.

Answer (score 12):

On Windows, there are two differences between mutexes and binary semaphores:

1. A mutex can only be released by the thread which has ownership, i.e. the thread which previously called the Wait function, (or which took ownership when creating it). A semaphore can be released by any thread.
2. A thread can call a wait function repeatedly on a mutex without blocking. However, if you call a wait function twice on a binary semaphore without releasing the semaphore in between, the thread will block.

Comment: Good answer.  In #2 you are describing a recursive mutex -- not all mutexes are necessarily recursive.  E.g., http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.FAQ.html#Q14

Answer (score 12):

Myth:

Couple of article says that "binary semaphore and mutex are same" or "Semaphore with value 1 is mutex" but the basic difference is Mutex can be released only by thread that had acquired it, while you can signal semaphore from any other thread

Key Points:

•A thread can acquire more than one lock (Mutex).

•A mutex can be locked more than once only if its a recursive mutex, here lock and unlock for mutex should be same

•If a thread which had already locked a mutex, tries to lock the mutex again, it will enter into the waiting list of that mutex, which results in deadlock.

•Binary semaphore and mutex are similar but not same.

•Mutex is costly operation due to protection protocols associated with it.

•Main aim of mutex is achieve atomic access or lock on resource

Answer (score 11):

Mutex are used for " Locking Mechanisms ". one process at a time can use a shared resource

whereas

Semaphores are used for " Signaling Mechanisms " 
like "I am done , now can continue"

Answer (score 10):

You obviously use mutex to lock a data in one thread getting accessed by another thread at the same time.  Assume that you have just called `lock()` and in the process of accessing data.  This means that you don’t expect any other thread (or another instance of the same thread-code) to access the same data locked by the same mutex.  That is, if it is the same thread-code getting executed on a different thread instance, hits the lock, then the `lock()` should block the control flow there.  This applies to a thread that uses a different thread-code, which is also accessing the same data and which is also locked by the same mutex.  In this case,  you are still in the process of accessing the data and you may take, say, another 15 secs to reach the mutex unlock (so that the other thread that is getting blocked in mutex lock would unblock and would allow the control to access the data). Do you at any cost allow yet another thread to just unlock the same mutex, and in turn, allow the thread that is already waiting (blocking) in the mutex lock to unblock and access the data?  Hope you got what I am saying here?
As per, agreed upon universal definition!,

- with “mutex” this can’t happen.  No other thread can unlock the lock
  in your thread
- with “binary-semaphore” this can happen. Any other thread can unlock
  the lock in your thread

So, if you are very particular about using binary-semaphore instead of mutex, then you should be very careful in “scoping” the locks and unlocks. I mean that every control-flow that hits every lock should hit an unlock call, also there shouldn’t be any “first unlock”, rather it should be always “first lock”.

Answer (score 7):

A *Mutex* controls access to a single shared resource. It provides operations to *acquire()* access to that resource and *release()* it when done.

A *Semaphore* controls access to a shared pool of resources. It provides operations to *Wait()* until one of the resources in the pool becomes available, and *Signal()* when it is given back to the pool.

When number of resources a Semaphore protects is greater than 1, it is called a *Counting Semaphore*. When it controls one resource, it is called a *Boolean Semaphore*. A boolean semaphore is equivalent to a mutex.

Thus a Semaphore is a higher level abstraction than Mutex. A Mutex can be implemented using a Semaphore but not the other way around.

Answer (score 6):

Modified question is - What's the difference between A mutex and a "binary" semaphore in "Linux"?

Ans: Following are the differences –
i) Scope – The scope of mutex is within a process address space which has created it and is used for synchronization of threads. Whereas semaphore can be used across process space and hence it can be used for interprocess synchronization.

ii) Mutex is lightweight and faster than semaphore. Futex is even faster.

iii) Mutex can be acquired by same thread successfully multiple times with condition that it should release it same number of times. Other thread trying to acquire will block. Whereas in case of semaphore if same process tries to acquire it again it blocks as it can be acquired only once.

Comment: i) Wrong. ii) Source? iii) It depends.

Answer (score 6):

Diff between Binary Semaphore and Mutex:
OWNERSHIP:
**Semaphores can be signalled (posted) even from a non current owner. It means you can simply post from any other thread, though you are not the owner.**

Semaphore is a public property in process, It can be simply posted by a non owner thread.
Please Mark this difference in BOLD letters, it mean a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Mutex work on blocking critical region, But Semaphore work on count.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/9102  discusses in details.

`Mutex` is locking mechanism used to synchronize access to a resource.
`Semaphore` is signaling mechanism.

Its up to to programmer if he/she wants to use  binary semaphore in place of mutex.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the fact that mutexes have an owner, the two objects may be optimized for different usage. Mutexes are designed to be held only for a short time; violating this can cause poor performance and unfair scheduling. For example, a running thread may be permitted to acquire a mutex, even though another thread is already blocked on it. Semaphores may provide more fairness, or fairness can be forced using several condition variables.

Comment: In which specific cases is fairness guaranteed for semaphores but not for mutexes?

Comment: POSIX has specific requirements which thread should be awakened by `sem_post()` for `SCHED_FIFO` and `SCHED_RR` (both of these are not default): the highest priority thread, and if there are multiple with the same priority, the thread that has been waiting the longest. OpenSolaris follows this FIFO rule to some degree even for normal scheduling. For glibc and FreeBSD, unlocking a simple mutex (i.e. not priority protect or priority inherit) and posting a semaphore are basically the same, marking the object as unlocked and then, if there may be waiting threads, calling the kernel to wake one.

Answer (score 4):

In windows the difference is as below.
**MUTEX:** process which successfully executes **wait** has to execute a **signal** and vice versa. **BINARY SEMAPHORES:** Different processes can execute **wait** or **signal** operation on a semaphore.

Answer (score 4):

The concept was clear to me after going over above posts. But there were some lingering questions. So, I wrote this small piece of code.

When we try to give a semaphore without taking it, it goes through. But, when you try to give a mutex without taking it, it fails. I tested this on a Windows platform. Enable USE_MUTEX to run the same code using a MUTEX.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define xUSE_MUTEX 1
#define MAX_SEM_COUNT 1

DWORD WINAPI Thread_no_1( LPVOID lpParam );
DWORD WINAPI Thread_no_2( LPVOID lpParam );

HANDLE Handle_Of_Thread_1 = 0;
HANDLE Handle_Of_Thread_2 = 0;
int Data_Of_Thread_1 = 1;
int Data_Of_Thread_2 = 2;
HANDLE ghMutex = NULL;
HANDLE ghSemaphore = NULL;


int main(void)
{

#ifdef USE_MUTEX
    ghMutex = CreateMutex( NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    if (ghMutex  == NULL) 
    {
        printf("CreateMutex error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
#else
    // Create a semaphore with initial and max counts of MAX_SEM_COUNT
    ghSemaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL,MAX_SEM_COUNT,MAX_SEM_COUNT,NULL);
    if (ghSemaphore == NULL) 
    {
        printf("CreateSemaphore error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
#endif
    // Create thread 1.
    Handle_Of_Thread_1 = CreateThread( NULL, 0,Thread_no_1, &Data_Of_Thread_1, 0, NULL);  
    if ( Handle_Of_Thread_1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Create first thread problem \n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* sleep for 5 seconds **/
    Sleep(5 * 1000);

    /*Create thread 2 */
    Handle_Of_Thread_2 = CreateThread( NULL, 0,Thread_no_2, &Data_Of_Thread_2, 0, NULL);  
    if ( Handle_Of_Thread_2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Create second thread problem \n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Sleep for 20 seconds
    Sleep(20 * 1000);

    printf("Out of the program \n");
    return 0;
}


int my_critical_section_code(HANDLE thread_handle)
{

#ifdef USE_MUTEX
    if(thread_handle == Handle_Of_Thread_1)
    {
        /* get the lock */
        WaitForSingleObject(ghMutex, INFINITE);
        printf("Thread 1 holding the mutex \n");
    }
#else
    /* get the semaphore */
    if(thread_handle == Handle_Of_Thread_1)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(ghSemaphore, INFINITE);
        printf("Thread 1 holding semaphore \n");
    }
#endif

    if(thread_handle == Handle_Of_Thread_1)
    {
        /* sleep for 10 seconds */
        Sleep(10 * 1000);
#ifdef USE_MUTEX
        printf("Thread 1 about to release mutex \n");
#else
        printf("Thread 1 about to release semaphore \n");
#endif
    }
    else
    {
        /* sleep for 3 secconds */
        Sleep(3 * 1000);
    }

#ifdef USE_MUTEX
    /* release the lock*/
    if(!ReleaseMutex(ghMutex))
    {
        printf("Release Mutex error in thread %d: error # %d\n", (thread_handle == Handle_Of_Thread_1 ? 1:2),GetLastError());
    }
#else
    if (!ReleaseSemaphore(ghSemaphore,1,NULL) )      
    {
        printf("ReleaseSemaphore error in thread %d: error # %d\n",(thread_handle == Handle_Of_Thread_1 ? 1:2), GetLastError());
    }
#endif

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI Thread_no_1( LPVOID lpParam ) 
{ 
    my_critical_section_code(Handle_Of_Thread_1);
    return 0;
}


DWORD WINAPI Thread_no_2( LPVOID lpParam ) 
{
    my_critical_section_code(Handle_Of_Thread_2);
    return 0;
}
```

The very fact that semaphore lets you signal "it is done using a resource", even though it never owned the resource, makes me think there is a very loose coupling between owning and signaling in the case of semaphores.

Comment: If you read the other answers, it's clear that the concept of "ownership" only makes sense with mutexes, not semaphores.  Semaphores could be used for things like a thread letting other threads know that processing of a chunk of data is done; results ready to be read.

Answer (score 4):

While a binary semaphore may be used as a mutex, a mutex is a more specific use-case, in that only the process that locked the mutex is supposed to unlock it. This ownership constraint makes it possible to provide protection against:

- Accidental release
- Recursive Deadlock
- Task Death Deadlock

These constraints are not always present because they degrade the speed. During the development of your code, you can enable these checks  temporarily.

e.g. you can enable Error check attribute in your mutex. Error checking mutexes return `EDEADLK` if you try to lock the same one twice and `EPERM` if you unlock a mutex that isn't yours.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
pthread_mutexattr_init (&attr);
pthread_mutexattr_settype (&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP);
pthread_mutex_init (&mutex, &attr);
```

Once initialised we can place these checks in our code like this:

```
if(pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex)==EPERM)
 printf("Unlock failed:Mutex not owned by this thread\n");
```

Answer (score 4):

**Best Solution**

The only difference is

1.Mutex -> lock and unlock are under the ownership of a thread that locks the mutex.

2.Semaphore -> No ownership i.e; if one thread calls semwait(s) any other thread can call sempost(s) to remove the lock.

Answer (score 2):

Mutex is used to protect the sensitive code and data, semaphore is used to synchronization.You also can have practical use with protect the sensitive code, but there might be a risk that release the protection by the other thread by operation V.So The main difference between bi-semaphore and mutex is the ownership.For instance by toilet , Mutex is like that one can enter the toilet and lock the door, no one else can enter until the man get out, bi-semaphore is like that one can  enter the toilet and lock the door, but someone else could enter by asking the administrator to open the door, it's ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

I think most of the answers here were confusing especially those saying that mutex can be released only by the process that holds it but semaphore can be signaled by ay process. The above line is kind of vague in terms of semaphore. To understand we should know that there are two kinds of semaphore one is called counting semaphore and the other is called a binary semaphore. In counting semaphore handles access to n number of resources where n can be defined before the use. Each semaphore has a count variable, which keeps the count of the number of resources in use, initially, it is set to n. Each process that wishes to uses a resource performs a wait() operation on the semaphore (thereby decrementing the count). When a process releases a resource, it performs a release() operation (incrementing the count). When the count becomes 0, all the resources are being used. After that, the process waits until the count becomes more than 0. Now here is the catch only the process that holds the resource can increase the count no other process can increase the count only the processes holding a resource can increase the count and the process waiting for the semaphore again checks and when it sees the resource available it decreases the count again. So in terms of binary semaphore, only the process holding the semaphore can increase the count, and count remains zero until it stops using the semaphore and increases the count and other process gets the chance to access the semaphore.

The main difference between binary semaphore and mutex is that semaphore is a signaling mechanism and mutex is a locking mechanism, but binary semaphore seems to function like mutex that creates confusion, but both are different concepts suitable for a different kinds of work.

Comment: This statement contrasts with the other answers: "So in terms of binary semaphore, only the process holding the semaphore can increase the count" - Semaphore, including binary semaphore, can be released by any other thread, not only the one who acquired the semaphore. That's all the other answers are saying.

Answer (score 1):

The answer may depend on the target OS.  For example, at least one RTOS implementation I'm familiar with will allow multiple sequential "get" operations against a single OS mutex, so long as they're all from within the same thread context.  The multiple gets must be replaced by an equal number of puts before another thread will be allowed to get the mutex.  *This differs from binary semaphores, for which only a single get is allowed at a time, regardless of thread contexts.*

The idea behind this type of mutex is that you protect an object by only allowing a single context to modify the data at a time.  Even if the thread gets the mutex and then calls a function that further modifies the object (and gets/puts the protector mutex around its own operations), the operations should still be safe because they're all happening under a single thread.

```
{
    mutexGet();  // Other threads can no longer get the mutex.

    // Make changes to the protected object.
    // ...

    objectModify();  // Also gets/puts the mutex.  Only allowed from this thread context.

    // Make more changes to the protected object.
    // ...

    mutexPut();  // Finally allows other threads to get the mutex.
}
```

Of course, when using this feature, you must be certain that all accesses within a single thread really are safe!

I'm not sure how common this approach is, or whether it applies outside of the systems with which I'm familiar.  For an example of this kind of mutex, see the ThreadX RTOS.

Comment: The kind of mutex you are talking about are called "recursive mutex" and should be avoided since they are slow and tend to promote bad design: (see David Butenhof: http://www.zaval.org/resources/library/butenhof1.html)

Comment: Agreed.  On this particular OS, I use the mutex service where I want to make it clear that the code is for "mutual exclusion" and not reference counting, but I don't use the recursive feature for fear of ugly unwinding.  Still, in the context of the question, this is an important difference between a "mutex" and "binary semaphore."

Answer (score 1):

Mutexes have ownership,  unlike  semaphores.   Although  any thread,  within  the  scope  of a mutex, can get an unlocked mutex and lock access to the same critical section of  code,*only the thread that locked a mutex **should** unlock it*.

Comment: what is ownership?You mean the context which acquires mutex can only un-aquire it.??

Answer (score 1):

As many folks here have mentioned, a mutex is used to protect a critical piece of code (AKA critical section.) You will acquire the mutex (lock), enter critical section, and release mutex (unlock) **all in the same thread**.

While using a semaphore, you can make a thread wait on a semaphore (say thread A), until another thread (say thread B)completes whatever task, and then sets the Semaphore for thread A to stop the wait, and continue its task.

Answer (score 1):

**MUTEX**

Until recently, the only sleeping lock in the kernel was the semaphore. Most users of semaphores instantiated a semaphore with a count of one and treated them as a mutual exclusion lock—a sleeping version of the spin-lock. Unfortunately, semaphores are rather generic and do not impose any usage constraints. This makes them useful for managing exclusive access in obscure situations, such as complicated dances between the kernel and userspace. But it also means that simpler locking is harder to do, and the lack of enforced rules makes any sort of automated debugging or constraint enforcement impossible. Seeking a simpler sleeping lock, the kernel developers introduced the mutex.Yes, as you are now accustomed to, that is a confusing name. Let’s clarify.The term “mutex” is a generic name to refer to any sleeping lock that enforces mutual exclusion, such as a semaphore with a usage count of one. In recent Linux kernels, the proper noun “mutex” is now also a specific type of sleeping lock that implements mutual exclusion.That is, a mutex is a mutex.

The simplicity and efficiency of the mutex come from the additional constraints it imposes on its users over and above what the semaphore requires. Unlike a semaphore, which implements the most basic of behaviour in accordance with Dijkstra’s original design, the mutex has a stricter, narrower use case:
n Only one task can hold the mutex at a time. That is, the usage count on a mutex is always one.

1. Whoever locked a mutex must unlock it. That is, you cannot lock a mutex in one
   context and then unlock it in another. This means that the mutex isn’t suitable for more complicated synchronizations between kernel and user-space. Most use cases,
   however, cleanly lock and unlock from the same context.
2. Recursive locks and unlocks are not allowed. That is, you cannot recursively acquire the same mutex, and you cannot unlock an unlocked mutex.
3. A process cannot exit while holding a mutex.
4. A mutex cannot be acquired by an interrupt handler or bottom half, even with
   mutex_trylock().
5. A mutex can be managed only via the official API: It must be initialized via the methods described in this section and cannot be copied, hand initialized, or reinitialized.

[1] Linux Kernel Development, Third Edition Robert Love

Answer (score 0):

Mutex and binary semaphore are both of the same usage, but in reality, they are different.

In case of mutex, only the thread which have locked it can unlock it. If any other thread comes to lock it, it will wait.

In case of semaphone, that's not the case. Semaphore is not tied up with a particular thread ID.

Answer (score 0):

The basic issue is concurrency. There is more than one flow of control. Think about two processes using a shared memory. Now only one process can access the shared memory at a time. If more than one process accesses the shared memory at a time, the contents of shared memory would get corrupted. It is like a railroad track. Only one train can run on it, else there would be an accident.So there is a signalling mechanism, which a driver checks. If the signal is green, the train can go and if it is red it has to wait to use the track. Similarly in case of shared memory, there is a binary semaphore. If the semaphore is 1, a process acquires it (makes it 0) and goes ahead and accesses it. If the semaphore is 0, the process waits. The functionality the binary semaphore has to provide is mutual exclusion (or mutex, in short) so that only one of the many concurrent entities (process or thread) mutually excludes others. It is a plus that we have counting semaphores, which help in synchronizing multiple instances of a resource.

Mutual exclusion is the basic functionality provided by semaphores. Now in the context of threads, we might have a different name and syntax for it. But the underlying concept is the same: how to keep integrity of code and data in concurrent programming. In my opinion, things like ownership, and associated checks are refinements provided by implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Mutex is a Criteria(Out of 4) that any algorithm that intends to solve the Critical Section Problem must follow whereas binary semaphore in itself is a variable that can take values 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

- Mutex uses a locking mechanism i.e. if a process wants to use a
  resource then it locks the resource, uses it and then release it. But
  on the other hand, semaphore uses a signalling mechanism where wait()
  and signal() methods are used to show if a process is releasing a
  resource or taking a resource.
- A mutex is an object but semaphore is an integer variable.
- In semaphore, we have wait() and signal() functions. But in mutex,
  there is no such function.
- A mutex object allows multiple process threads to access a single
  shared resource but only one at a time. On the other hand, semaphore
  allows multiple process threads to access the finite instance of the
  resource until available.
- In mutex, the lock can be acquired and released by the same process
  at a time. But the value of the semaphore variable can be modified by
  any process that needs some resource but only one process can change
  the value at a time.

A useful read, I learned and copied from [here](https://afteracademy.com/blog/difference-between-mutex-and-semaphore-in-operating-system)

Answer (score 0):

While there are over 30 answers, no one mentioned the following

In linux, there is another HUGE difference that `pthread_mutex_lock()` is not a cancellation point while `sem_wait()` is.

It is relevant when thread A hold a mutex/semaphore and want to `pthread_cancel()` thread B that is currently waiting that mutex/semaphore. If mutex is used, the behavior observed in my environment is that both thread A and thread B will wait each other and will be blocked forever

From `man pthread_cancel`

> A thread's cancellation type, determined by pthread_setcanceltype(3), may be either asynchronous  or  deferred  (the  default  for  new
> threads).
> Deferred cancelability means that cancellation will be delayed until the thread next calls a function that is a  can‐
> cellation point.  A list of functions that are or may be cancellation points is provided in pthreads(7).

And from `man 7 pthreads`

> ```
>    The following functions are required to be cancellation points by POSIX.1-2001 and/or POSIX.1-2008:
>       ...
>       sem_wait()
>       ...
> ```

Suprisingly (at least to me), `pthread_mutex_lock()` is not on the list.

Please refer to Manual page pthreads(7) and pthread_cancel(3)

Answer (score -2):

"binary semaphore" is a programming language circumvent to use a «semaphore» like «mutex». Apparently there are two very big differences:

1. The way you call each one of them.
2. The maximum length of the "identifier".

Answer (score -3):

You can clearly remember difference by this:

1. Mutex lock : is for protecting critical region,
   Mutex can't be used across processes, only used in single process
2. Semaphore: is for signalling availability of a resource.
   Semaphore can be used both across processes and across processes.

Comment: Interprocess mutexes are possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389730/is-it-possible-to-use-mutex-in-multiprocessing-case-on-linux-unix/9426906#9426906

Answer (score -4):

Almost all of the above said it right. Let me also try my bit to clarify if somebody still has a doubt.

- Mutex -> used for serialization
- Semaphore-> synchronization.

Purpose of both are different however, same functionality could be achieved through both of them with careful programming.

Standard Example-> producer consumer problem.

```
initial value of SemaVar=0

Producer                           Consumer
---                                SemaWait()->decrement SemaVar   
produce data
---
SemaSignal SemaVar or SemaVar++  --->consumer unblocks as SemVar is 1 now.
```

Hope I could clarify.

Comment: *same functionality could be achieved through both of them*.  A mutex might check that it's only unlocked by the same thread that locked it, because anything else is an error *for a mutex*.  If you want to wait until another thread has redirected `stdout`, or something like that, there's no obvious way to implement that with a mutex.  Are you going to take / release a lock around every use of `stdout`?  That doesn't even work, you wouldn't know whether the other thread has taken/released the mutex yet.

Comment: If you remove that claim, the example is maybe useful.