# mutex locking-unlocking producer-consumer scenario

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I have been reading about difference between binary semaphore and mutex and reading below link [mutex vs binary semaphore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814/difference-between-binary-semaphore-and-mutex) it says "**Mutex can be released only by thread that had acquired it**, while you can signal semaphore from any other thread (or process), so semaphores are more suitable for some synchronization problems like producer-consumer"

however in below example I am locking mutex in one thread and releasing it in another thread. Have I mis-understood the statement from the link presented or I have wrong understanding of my own implementation ? Again I was just poking around the code to have more better understanding of things and I was not expecting things to work but to my surprise it works fine.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define WORKERS 2
#define ARRAY_ELEMENTS 100
#define MAX 1000

pthread_mutex_t arraynotfull = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t access_array = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t arraynotempty = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

bool available = false;

void *worker_thread(void *pbucket)
{
    while(1)
    {
        unsigned int count = 0;
        int local_array[ARRAY_ELEMENTS];
        int *ptbucket = (int*)pbucket;
        setbuf(stdout, NULL);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&arraynotempty);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&access_array);
        while(count < ARRAY_ELEMENTS)
        {
            local_array[count] = ptbucket[count];
            count++;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&access_array);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&arraynotfull);   //unlocking in consumer

        count = 0;

        while(count < ARRAY_ELEMENTS)
        {
            printf(" %d - \n", local_array[count]);
            count++;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread_id[WORKERS];

    unsigned int* pbucket1 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * ARRAY_ELEMENTS);

    unsigned int* pbucket = pbucket1;

    for(int i = 0; i < WORKERS - 1; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, worker_thread, (void *) pbucket);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        unsigned int count = 0;

        // Make the payload ready
        pthread_mutex_lock(&arraynotfull);  // locking in producer
        pthread_mutex_lock(&access_array);
        while(count < ARRAY_ELEMENTS)
        {
            pbucket1[count] = i;
            i++;
            count++;
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&access_array);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&arraynotempty);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < WORKERS; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(thread_id[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read the comments under [the top voted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/62883/3003365) answer in the question you linked to. It addresses your question exactly. Or for a seperate question on this exact issue: [Pthread Mutex lock unlock by different threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454746/pthread-mutex-lock-unlock-by-different-threads/5492499#5492499).

Comment: I think I got the answer from the other link that you provided. Thank you for the reference. appreciate it !!!