# Acquiring a RwLock for read and keep it beyond the scope

Tags: multithreading, rust, rwlock

I have a thread that periodically calls a callback function. Depending on the state, the callback function shall acquire an `RwLock` of a resource shared with other threads and keep the resource locked even beyond the scope of the callback function. It shall then again depending on the state release the resource again in a later callback cycle.

My idea was to put an `Option<RwLockReadGuard<T>>` into a struct which would be `None` when the resource is not locked and `Some(RwLockReadGuard<T>)` when the resource is locked.

Unfortunately, I can't make this work. I have to set up the struct which contains the `Option<RwLockReadGuard<T>>` outside the thread of the callback function. Even though at the time the struct is moved into the thread the `Option` is `None`, the compiler won't let me pass the option because ``` the trait bound ``std::sync::RwLockReadGuard<'_, T>: std::marker::Send`` is not satisfied ```.

Maybe some code. I hope it's self-explaining enough.

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock, RwLockReadGuard};


struct Handler<'a> {
        resource: Arc<RwLock<String>>,
        locked_resource: Option<RwLockReadGuard<'a, String>>,
        counter: usize,
}

impl<'a> Handler<'a> {
        fn callback(&'a mut  self) {
                println!("Callback {}", self.counter);
                if self.counter == 0 {
                        println!("Locking resource");
                        let res = self.resource.read().unwrap();
                        self.locked_resource = Some(res);
                }

                self.counter += 1;

                if self.counter == 100 {
                        println!("Releasing resource");
                        self.locked_resource = None;
                }

                if self.counter == 200 {
                        self.counter = 0;
                }
        }
}


fn main() {
        let resource = Arc::new(RwLock::new("foo".to_string()));

        let handler = Handler {
                resource: resource.clone(),
                locked_resource: None,
                counter: 0
        };

        // This gives E0277
        let thread = thread::spawn( move || {
                loop {
                        handler.callback();
                }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is: locking and unlocking *need* to occur on the same thread. This is, for example, a limitation of [pthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454746/pthread-mutex-lock-unlock-by-different-threads).

Fortunately, the Rust type system is expressive enough to model this: by making `RwLockReadGuard` be `!Send`, it prevents locks to be accidentally shared! All hail Rust!

So you *can* lock and unlock in different callback functions... but on the same thread.

In your example, this is as simple as moving the creation of `handler` inside the thread. In your real application, it might be a bit more complicated, but rest assured: the compiler will hold your hand along the way ;)

```
fn main() {
    let resource = Arc::new(RwLock::new("foo".to_string()));

    let thread = thread::spawn( move || {
        let handler = Handler {
                resource: resource,
                locked_resource: None,
                counter: 0
        };

        loop {
                handler.callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have thought of this and tried your solution. But then it says `handler might not live long enough`.

But that is not an option anyway because in my real project I don't setup the thread myself. I just hand in a trait object with the call back function and a library starts the thread.

Comment: Interesting error, which has nothing to do with the `Mutex` question: you cannot [borrow from a sibling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct). As for your issue, I'm sorry, but them's are rule. You cannot lock from a thread, unlock from another thread, and expect things to work: you *have* to design your program in another way.

Comment: But it's the same thread, isn't it? It's one thread that keeps calling `callback()` over and over again. I want it to keep the lock across several of those cycles.

Comment: @JohannesMueller: Are you sure it is? What if the library uses a thread-pool? What if the current version of the library doesn't use a thread-pool but the next does (ie, beware of using `unsafe` to bypass the restriction)? In any case, you currently have the problem that you cannot take a lock on a sibling field, maybe solving *that* issue will guide you toward another more accommodating design?