# How can I solve conflict between read thread and write thread of /proc file in linux kernel?

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, circular-buffer, read-write

I have a Linux kernel module which creates a file in `/proc` directory. My module has read function and write functions which are called when the file is read or written.  It has a circular buffer to save data which has many buffer entrys.

When the file is written, the module will write data in circular buffer which is then read when the `/proc` file is read.

When there are 2 threads, one thread may be writing into a buffer entry at the same time a read thread is reading from that buffer entry.

Will there be conflicts?  How can i solve conflict between read thread and write thread?

Comment: This page may be helpful: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-5#chp-5

Comment: use synchronization primitives like mutex,semaphore depending on what u need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814/difference-between-binary-semaphore-and-mutex