# Multithreading,blocking and semaphores

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, thread-safety, pthreads

(1) In a multi-threaded process,If one thread is busy on I/O will the entire process be blocked?

(2) Which is better to use a mutex or a binary semaphore ? When should I use a mutex and when should I use a binary Semaphore ?

Comment: No.  A mutex is owned by a specific thread, a semaphore is not.

Comment: 1) No. 2) You should almost always use a mutex instead of a semaphore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1). Well, at a time only one thread is allocated the CPU in multithreaded application. If you are saying that your thread is regularly busy with I/O, then practically it can happen that all other threads keep waiting in queue to get CPU allocated to them. It depends upon the CPU `allocation algorithm` used. Like if thread are using `Time-Sharing` algorithm, then of course on completion of time, current thread will be send to the back of the queue.

2). Check out this post: - [Difference between binary semaphore and mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814/difference-between-binary-semaphore-and-mutex)

Comment: @Abhishek.. You're Welcome..If your problem is solved, you can accept it as answer to mark this question resolved..

Comment: Generally, peforming I/O operations allows other threads that are ready to run to get CPU, (certainly on any OS with a preemptive scheduler, ie. just about all of them).

Comment: That also depends upon the priority of the thread busy with I/O operation.. If its priority is high enough, it will not be pre-empted..

Answer (score 0):

1) In a SMP environment multiple thread can run in parallel(on different cpu). In a single CPU environment, only one thread would be running at a time.

2) read this [diff-binary-semaphore-and-mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814/difference-between-binary-semaphore-and-mutex)