# Can we achieve semaphore like behavior using synchronization primitives in pthread library?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, semaphore

I went through semaphores API's offered in Linux. A simple usage of semaphore would be

```
sem_wait()
   //do something       
sem_post()
```

Can a similar behavior be achieved by using available synchronization primitives in pthread library?

After going through POSIX API's i have come up with following code:

```
int a = COUNT_LIMIT; //global variable
pthread_mutex_t m1;
pthread_cond_t c1;

 pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
   while(a==0){
   pthread_cond_wait(&c1, &m1);  
 }
a--;
//do whatever i want to do, as resource is available
pthread_cond_signal(&c1,&m1);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
```

I believe this code would do the trick, but what is the best followed practice to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only hold the mutex while you are testing and changing `a`.

```
sem_wait() {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
   while (a == 0) pthread_cond_wait(&c1, &m1);
   a--;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
}
sem_post() {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
   a++;
   pthread_cond_signal(&c1);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
}
```

The real question is, [*why* would you want semaphores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814/difference-between-binary-semaphore-and-mutex)?  Unless you really have a set of truly indistinguishable resources mutexes tend to be easier to reason about since they require the locker to unlock them.  For example, with mutexes you can do deadlock detection by detecting cycles in a waits-for graph, whereas for semaphores you need to use more complicated deadlock detection algorithms like [Dijkstra's Banker's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banker's_algorithm).