# Python binary semaphore VS lock

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, concurrency, locking

We're working in multithreaded python environment and need a mutual exclusion for a piece of code like:

```
lock = threading.Lock()
with lock:
    # get data from shared storage
    # process
    # put back to shared storage
```

Currently it seems to me that binary semaphore `threading.Semaphore()` and lock `threading.Lock()`
will similarly serve for this. Are there some pitfalls or gainings if I switch from lock to binary semaphore or vice versa?

NOTE: code running inside greenthreads (if that changes situation)

Comment: I believe you can find a good explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814/difference-between-binary-semaphore-and-mutex

Answer (score -4, accepted):

`threading.Semaphore()` uses a `threading.Lock()` object internally as a monitor. When `Semaphore.acquire()` is called, the semaphore object calls acquire on its Lock object, decrements its value, and releases the lock.

From this it follows that a binary Semaphore is really just a wrapper around a Lock. I cannot think of any functional difference between the two, except that with Semaphore you can pass the optional `verbose = True` parameter for debugging purposes, and have the option to call acquire with `blocking = False`.

Comment: Thanks! BTW Lock also has lock.acquire(blocking=False) option

Answer (score 0):

It can be said that Semaphore is an advanced version of Lock. Semaphore has a custom number to control multiple threads to access resources. But there is only one with Lock.