# what is the difference between binary semaphore and mutex?

Tags: synchronization, multithreading, semaphore

I would like to know the difference between binary semaphore and mutex?
Are these same? Binary semaphore will have value of 1 and 0, with mutex like lock and unlock.

I am really confused about these terms. I am talking an application level programming perspective. In an interview I was asked about this question and explained them that semaphore are meant for signalling and mutex is for locking. Please explain with simple example. I googled, but came to know that the apart from the above difference, semaphore locks can be unlocked by other threads whereas mutex locks must be unlocked by thread who locked it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between binary semaphore and mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814/difference-between-binary-semaphore-and-mutex)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you view that.

On **concept layer** *binary semaphore* provide *mutual exclusion* - guarantee that only one thread will enter a critical section. I.e. Tanenbaum in his book "Operating Systems" Ed. 3 introduces mutexes with the following sentence:

> When the semaphore's ability to count is not needed, a simplified version of semaphore called a mutex is sometimes used.

However, *semaphore* is usually a reference to classical Dijkstra concept with `P()` and `V()` functions, while *mutex* is very broad term. That's what Linus Torvalds says on semaphores:

> A spinlock is a mutual exclusion mechanism, not a semaphore (a semaphore
>   is a very specific *kind* of mutual exclusion).

(from comp.os.linux.development.system: [Re: NT kernel guy playing with Linux](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/semaphores.html))

On **implementation layer** *mutexes* may be implemented as *semaphores*, i.e. in Linux 2.4: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-i386/semaphore.h?v=2.4.37#L89

Usually *mutex* has much more complex implementation and wider concept:

- Mutex has `owner` field -- thread that currently entered mutex. It provides various benefits like re-enterable mutexes, priority inversion, etc.
- While *semaphore* is usually blocks thread that fails to acquire it, *mutex* may be adaptive (like in Solaris) that could *spin* (busy-wait until mutex is unlocked).
- *Semaphore* usually implemented via incrementing/decrementing counter, but *mutexes* may use atomic exchange and test operations.

Some of that ideas came from Wikipedia: [w:Semaphore (programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29#Semaphores_vs._mutexes)