# What is the timing to use semMCreate or semBCreate?

Tags: vxworks

When should I use `semMCreate` vs. `semBCreate`?  In my opinion, they are both the same.

Answer (score 1):

`semMCreate` creates a Mutex Semaphore, `semBCreate` creates a Binary Semaphore, and they are actually quite different.

**Very** basically: you use the Mutex to protect a critical section of code, and you use a Binary Semaphore to synchronize access to a shared resource. Especially in VxWorks.

You can find more information in the answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814/difference-between-binary-semaphore-and-mutex).

Bye!