# Difference between Mutex and Semaphore=1?

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic, mutex, semaphore

Is there any difference between the following two variables:

```
Mutex m;
Semaphore s = 1;
```

I think they are the same but in a video I am watching about a formula to the reader/writer problem, it says to use `5` semaphores, each of them starting at the value of `1`. I find that interesting because I thought if you have a semaphore at the value of `1`, then you would just use a mutex.

Comment: @DougCurrie Thank you. I would have never known to search *Binary Semaphore*. This has all the information I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of Mutex as being in a subset of the definition of a semaphore.

There is a good answer on Stack Overflow here: [Difference between binary semaphore and mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814/difference-between-binary-semaphore-and-mutex) .

> Mutex can be released only by thread that had acquired it, while you
>   can signal semaphore from any other thread (or process), so semaphores
>   are more suitable for some synchronization problems like
>   producer-consumer.