# Semaphore in Java/Operating Systems

Tags: java, concurrency, mutex, semaphore

I am new in the forum and in programming in general.At the moment i study "Operation Systems" and Java.
This week we started the topic "Semaphores" and it seems to me that it's a bit confusing.
I have this exercise:

shared variable  `numberofworks = 0`

```
    EmployeeA 
    {
        while (True) {
            A_works_outside();
            A_works_inside();
            numberofworks =numberofworks + 1;
        }
    }

    EmployeeB
    {
        while (True) {
            B_works_outside();
            B_works_inside();
            numberofworks =numberofworks + 1;
        }
    }
```

well,the exercise wants to use semaphores (P and V) so

1. In i repetition of EmployeeA the `A_works_inside()` runs only when B_works_outside() is finished
2. In i repetition of EmployeeB the `Β_works_inside()` runs only when Α_works_outside() is finished
3. Variable `numberofworks` must be the sum of `numberofworksA + numberofworksB`

I must write the code in Java and in "operation system"
before helping me in this exercise (if you can of course) General questions in semaphores:
What's the basic difference between mutex and a sempahore?
and how should i understand when to use mutex or not?

Comment: `P=Semaphore.acquire` and `V=Semaphore.release` but that is probably entirely clear. Where Dijkstra coined P = Dutch passeren = pass, V = vrij geven = give free = release.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use a resource protected by a Mutex:

```
- Hi! Can I ?
*If free*
- Yup go on.
*Else*
- No, go away!
```

Trying to use a resource protected by a Semaphore:

```
- Hi! Can I ?
*If free*
- Yup go on.
*Else*
- No, wait in the queue!
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814/difference-between-binary-semaphore-and-mutex