# Actual difference between Mutex and Binary semaphore

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, mutex, semaphore, binary-semaphore

So, last week, I was researching about Mutex and Semaphores. I came to find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814/difference-between-binary-semaphore-and-mutex) which really helped me figure out what Semaphores are. Now that I understand what the *theorical* difference is, between **Binary** Semaphore and Mutex, I still wonder *how* to *actually* use them. I'm currently using C# and I can't find any way to use a **Binary** Semaphore in this language.

Can someone please post any (simple) code example on how to use **Binary** Semaphore vs Mutex ? Any widely used language would do the job. You can even post a Powershell/Bash script.

Comment: You question title suggests you want to know about differences between them, but the body of your question asks for code examples. So what do you need?

Comment: I want to know the actual (as opposed to theorical) differences between the two. Therefore, showing a piece of code would be worth a thousand words. Though, documentation on both mutex and binary semaphore provided by a same OS/language would be relevant too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very coarse approximation is if your thread of execution needs to block while holding a resource (ie. mutex, sem), you shouldn't use a mutex.  The problem with that approximation is that block means something different in a UI program and an interrupt handler; blocking is a relative notion.

Mutexes are bound to owners; Semaphores are not.  The only agent that can release a mutex is the one that acquired it.  Semaphores do not have this limitation.  Because of this limitation, if a low priority agent blocks a high priority agent on a mutex, the supervisor (kernel, whatever..) can boost the priority of the owner until it relinquishes it.  This can be applied transitively to solve non-cyclic priority inversion.   You cannot do this with semaphores, since they lack the concept of an owner.

For example, thread 1 can acquire a semaphore, thread 2 can wait on it, and thread 3 can relinquish it.  That might sound like chaos, but it might be the foundation of a more sophisticated system where thread 3 and 1 are communicating via some means, so thread 1 can hand ownership of a resource over to thread 3 directly.  This can't be done with mutexes.

That said; I could like hack a *pthread_mutex_transfer(mutex, pthread)* into any existing implementation, thumbing my nose at the purists and theoreticians.

Comment: "_you shouldn't use a mutex_" why not?

Comment: re: coarse approximation.  Consider synchronizing with an interrupt handler.  If you block holding a mutex, say waiting for an event from a different device, you have now bound the interrupting device to the signalling one.  Furthermore, the interrupting device may cause other devices interrupts to be delayed ( a not uncommon interrupt structure ), including the one you are blocked on.   Even cycle-detection would likely miss this, since part of the cycle is hidden in some exterior bus device.

Comment: You can construct similar things with UI-type code where a dialog goes to sleep holding say a file access mutex, while another part of the program wants to auto-save, but is blocked by the file access mutex.   It makes programs more sluggish and quirky than their design frameworks.