# Binary Semaphore vs Mutux interview question

Tags: linux, mutex, semaphore, rtos

I have below questions:

When to use binary semaphore and when to use mutex?
What is internal difference?

Majorly in interview this question is asked.

Comment: Quite interesting that the question was closed with "not focused" as it is the entirely same question which was asked and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814/difference-between-binary-semaphore-and-mutex. So it is a duplicate :-)

Comment: @Klaus: "not focused" was a reason I voted to close as the question contained multiple different questions

Comment: @NicoHaase: My understanding is different. OP asks for mutex vs semaphore and the typical use cases and implementation details. That is such hard related, that it is more a wish for a deep explanation which is according to the rules of SO in my opinion. But as said: Exactly this is already answered...